# nginx+php-fpm+phpmyadminセットアップ　phpファイルが動かない

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

お世話になっております。
こちらのサイトにかなり助けてもらってます。何卒教えて下さい。

表題の件で、CentOS7にnginxをのせ、php-fpmを使用して、phpファイルを実行しておりました。
が、その後phpmyadminを設定して疎通確認後に、再度phpファイルへアクセスした所
「access denied」が出てしまいました。nginx.conf設定ファイルを色々変更していたせいかと
思っております。また、nginx/nginx.logやhtmlコンテキスト内に記載したパスでのerror.logには何も吐かれていませんでした。

1. (サーバIPアドレス)/test.php 以前まで実行できていた。
   ↓
2. (サーバIPアドレス)/phpmyadmin 設定後、実行できるようになった
   ↓
3. (サーバIPアドレス)/test.phpがaccess deniedになった

という流れです。

不自然な所や、その他のファイル等の確認事項がございましたら、ご教示願いたく存じます。

環境：CentOS7 php5.4
設定状況：ドキュメントディレクトリ /etc/nginx/www
上記のディレクトリにtest.phpやhtmlファイルがおいてあります。

下記設定ファイルの抜粋です。
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (default.confは使用していない)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  〜中略〜
  location / {
    root /etc/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php
  }

  location ~ ¥.php$ {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /etc/nginx/www$fast_cgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED /etc/nginx/www$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location /phpmyadmin {
    root usr/share;
    index index.php;

    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin.+¥.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /etc/nginx/www$fast_cgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
  〜中略〜
}
```

/etc/php.ini

```
〜中略〜
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
〜中略〜
```

なかなかphpmyadminの設定がうまくいかず、試行錯誤しておりましたせいで、
お恥ずかしながらどのように設定を変えたかわからなくなってしまいました。
権限設定の面は可能性が薄いかと思います。nginx.confの設定か、php-fpmの設定かなぁと
思っています。かなり悩み疲れしてしまっております。

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: selinuxは有効ですか？`getenforce`を実行して`Enforcing`と返れば有効です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
selinuxを無効(setenforce=0)にしてみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。他に何か原因は考えられませんでしょうか

Comment: すみません、解決しました!! fastcgi_param TRANSLATEDをコメントアウトし、かつfastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAMEがSCRIPT_FILENAMEの間違いでした。超凡ミスでした。。。。大変失礼致しました。

Answer (score 1):

([質問者さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/14604/sato)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/22672/nginxphp-fpmphpmyadmin%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97-php%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8C%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/51425#comment21656_22672)より)

`fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED`をコメントアウトし、かつ`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME`が`SCRIPT_FILENAME`の間違いでした。

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
server {

  ...

  location ~ ¥.php$ {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /etc/nginx/www$fast_cgi_script_name;
   #fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED /etc/nginx/www$fastcgi_path_info;      ### <- この行をコメントアウト
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location /phpmyadmin {
    root usr/share;
    index index.php;

    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin.+¥.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
     #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /etc/nginx/www$fast_cgi_script_name;     ### <- SCRIPT_NAME ではなく
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /etc/nginx/www$fast_cgi_script_name; ### <- SCRIPT_FILENAME
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```